# SQLite inserting multiple rows with same value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created a DownloadManager to donwload two files from within a RecyclerView adapter, getting the links from the items,

after donwloading it saves the files on external storage, copys it to internal, then deletes from external,

and then i save the path to the files on SQLite db, to then show it on another RecyclerView.

So far everything is working

the only thing is that it saves the row multiple times on db, as if the code was on a loop, and i say that because,i set a toast for when db ops and downloads are finished, and those toasts appear multiple times, as well as the entries saved on db.

on the other recyclerview there are multiple items appearing, that are all the same

i set an onclick listener and i execute this code on Click

```
holder.downloadBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    if (CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(ctx, DBConstants.SavedItemsEntry.TABLE_NAME, DBConstants.SavedItemsEntry.COLUMN_TITLE, Title)) {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Item ja Existente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        DownloadClick(pdfurl, image, Title, Title);
                        BroadCReciever(Title, desc);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
```

the code that seems to loop is on BroadCast reciever

here's code of broadcast reciever:

```
private void BroadCReciever(final String filename, final String desc){

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)){


                    //IMAGE REQUEST QUERY SOLVER
                    DownloadManager.Query req_query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    req_query.setFilterById(queue_id_img);

                    final Cursor c = dm.query(req_query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) checkStatus(c,"image");
                    {

                        int columnindex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL==c.getInt(columnindex))
                        {
                            //DATA OBJECT
                            String UriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            final Uri i = Uri.parse(UriString);
                            final File f = new File(i.getPath());

                            try {
                                Bitmap im;
                                im = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ctx.getContentResolver(),i);
                                // Initializing a new file
                                // The bellow line return a directory in internal storage
                                File fileimg = ctx.getDir("Images",MODE_PRIVATE);
                                // Create a file to save the image
                                fileimg = new File(fileimg, filename+".jpg");
                                try {
                                    OutputStream stream = null;

                                    stream = new FileOutputStream(fileimg);
                                    im.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
                                    stream.flush();
                                    stream.close();
                                }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                //checking is image file exists in Internal Storage
                                if(fileimg.exists()) {
                                    String internal_uri = fileimg.getAbsolutePath();
                                    img_internal_uri = internal_uri;
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "doesnt exist image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                //deleting file from external storage
                                if (f.exists()){
                                    Boolean deleted = f.delete();

                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    //IMAGE REQUEST QUERY SOLVER END




                    //PDF REQUEST QUERY SOLVER
                    DownloadManager.Query req_query2 = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    req_query2.setFilterById(queue_id_pdf);

                    final Cursor c2 = dm.query(req_query2);
                    if (c2.moveToFirst()) checkStatus(c2,"pdf");
                    {
                        int columnindex2 = c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL==c2.getInt(columnindex2))
                        {
                            //DATA OBJECT
                            String UriString = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            final Uri i = Uri.parse(UriString);
                            final File f = new File(i.getPath());

                                if (f.exists()){
                                    // Initializing a new file
                                    // The bellow line return a directory in internal storage
                                    File file = ctx.getDir("PDF",MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    // Create a file to save the pdf
                                    file = new File(file,filename+".pdf");

                                    try {
                                        OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(f);
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                        int length;
                                        while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                            outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                        }
                                        instream.close();
                                        outstream.flush();
                                        outstream.close();
                                    }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    if (file.exists()) {
                                        String internal_uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
                                        pdf_internal_uri = internal_uri;
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "doesnt exist pdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    Boolean deleted = f.delete();

                                }


                        }
                    }
                    //PDF REQUEST QUERY SOLVER END

                    checkifDOne(c,c2,filename,desc,img_internal_uri,pdf_internal_uri);
                }

            }

        };
        ctx.registerReceiver(receiver,  new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
```

the method checkifDOne is the one that saves the data
here:

```
public void checkifDOne(Cursor c, Cursor c2, String Title, String desc, String img, String pdf){
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
        int status = c.getInt(columnIndex);

        int columnIndex2 = c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
        int status2 = c2.getInt(columnIndex);

        if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL && status2 == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
            saveToDB(ctx,Title,desc,img,pdf);
        }
    }
```

and in that method we have the :

```
public void saveToDB(Context c,String title, String desc, String img, String pdf){
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(c);
        db.openDB();
        long result = db.add(title,desc,img,pdf);
        if (result == 1){
            Toast.makeText(c, "item salvo para leitura offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(c, img, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(c, pdf, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(c, "Erro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        db.CloseDB();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are miss-using the BroadcastReceiver. As it is right now, every time you call you **BroadCReceiver** function you create and register a new receiver. So if you call it ten times, then you'll have the job done ten times.

What you need to do is get rid of the **BroadCReceiver** function and leave only the `receiver` declaration as a field in your class, just leave this:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)){


                //IMAGE REQUEST QUERY SOLVER
                DownloadManager.Query req_query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                req_query.setFilterById(queue_id_img);

                final Cursor c = dm.query(req_query);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) checkStatus(c,"image");
                {

                    int columnindex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL==c.getInt(columnindex))
                    {
                        //DATA OBJECT
                        String UriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                        final Uri i = Uri.parse(UriString);
                        final File f = new File(i.getPath());

                        try {
                            Bitmap im;
                            im = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ctx.getContentResolver(),i);
                            // Initializing a new file
                            // The bellow line return a directory in internal storage
                            File fileimg = ctx.getDir("Images",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            // Create a file to save the image
                            fileimg = new File(fileimg, filename+".jpg");
                            try {
                                OutputStream stream = null;

                                stream = new FileOutputStream(fileimg);
                                im.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
                                stream.flush();
                                stream.close();
                            }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            //checking is image file exists in Internal Storage
                            if(fileimg.exists()) {
                                String internal_uri = fileimg.getAbsolutePath();
                                img_internal_uri = internal_uri;
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ctx, "doesnt exist image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            //deleting file from external storage
                            if (f.exists()){
                                Boolean deleted = f.delete();

                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                //IMAGE REQUEST QUERY SOLVER END




                //PDF REQUEST QUERY SOLVER
                DownloadManager.Query req_query2 = new DownloadManager.Query();
                req_query2.setFilterById(queue_id_pdf);

                final Cursor c2 = dm.query(req_query2);
                if (c2.moveToFirst()) checkStatus(c2,"pdf");
                {
                    int columnindex2 = c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                    if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL==c2.getInt(columnindex2))
                    {
                        //DATA OBJECT
                        String UriString = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                        final Uri i = Uri.parse(UriString);
                        final File f = new File(i.getPath());

                            if (f.exists()){
                                // Initializing a new file
                                // The bellow line return a directory in internal storage
                                File file = ctx.getDir("PDF",MODE_PRIVATE);
                                // Create a file to save the pdf
                                file = new File(file,filename+".pdf");

                                try {
                                    OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                    InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(f);
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                    int length;
                                    while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                        outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                    }
                                    instream.close();
                                    outstream.flush();
                                    outstream.close();
                                }catch (IOException e) // Catch the exception
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                if (file.exists()) {
                                    String internal_uri = file.getAbsolutePath();
                                    pdf_internal_uri = internal_uri;
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "doesnt exist pdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                Boolean deleted = f.delete();

                            }


                    }
                }
                //PDF REQUEST QUERY SOLVER END

                checkifDOne(c,c2,filename,desc,img_internal_uri,pdf_internal_uri);
            }

        }

    };
```

So now `receiver` is unique in your class.

And then you need to register it and unregister it according to your needs in the *Activity?* (or what ever other main class you are using) lifecycle. For example you can register it in onStart and unregister it in onStop like:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(receiver,  new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

And finally when you want to send the broadcast event (your click event on downloadBTN) just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This way you will only have one receiver that's registered/unregistered as your needs and will correctly handle your task only once per click.

Alternatively, you can register your receiver in your manifest. If you need me to I can explain how to do it